# Android Tests does not recognize my test method

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am trying to add some unit tests to my android app. Following is what I tried.

Created a directory for my tests and created a package for test classes inside it.

Created following test class in added package

```
public class MyFirstTest extends TestCase {

        @Override
        protected void setUp() throws Exception {
            super.setUp();
        }

        @SmallTest
        public void basicTest() {
            assertEquals("abc", "abc");
        }

        @Override
        protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
            super.tearDown();
        }
    }
```

Created a new `Android Tests` build configuration in Android Studio

Specified module in build configuration settings and choose to run test cases of my test class (specified class name `MyFirstTest`  in build configuration settings)

But, when I run my build configuration, it says that no tests were found in `MyFirstTest` class.

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in my.package.tests.MyFirstTest
```

What should I do to make `basicTest()` method to get identified as a test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must name your tests `testSomething()`, that is starting with `test`